# duplicate icon on docky

Tags: wine, icons, docky

I got a problem with docky dock on 18.04 : in few words, it displays a duplicate icon for LTspice running under wine even if the StartupWMClass is set correctly, i.e. the output of

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

choosing the ".exe" entry `xviix64.exe`. This problem doesn't exist on other docks (I tried on dash-to-dock, Cairo-dock, Latte-dock).

If you need it, I can provide my ".desktop" launcher, but as I said, I don't think it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the problem is, but for anyone wondering, a workaround is to create a bash script only containing the command in `Exec` entry of the launcher and then using that script instead in the launcher itself.

```
# workaround.sh
#!/bin/bash

`wine /path/.../yourapp.exe`
```

```
....
Exec=workaround.sh
...
```